# MySQL auto_increment not incrementing

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I'm using MySQL 5.x and I don't know why I the auto_increment isn't working. I set the addressID as Primary Key in the AddressInformation and the addressID in PersonalInformation as the Foreign Key for AddressInformation's addressID. Is this the cause? When I update it via Workbench, it's working but when I update it via JDBC, it isn't working. It throws and parameter index out of range error. Here's the code for the two tables

```
CREATE TABLE  PersonalInformation  (
   Username  VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
   Lastname  VARCHAR(50),
   Firstname  VARCHAR(50),
   Middlename  VARCHAR(50),
   Gender  CHAR(1),
   Birthdate  VARCHAR(50),
   AddressID  INT NOT NULL,
   Email  VARCHAR(50),
   PhoneNumber  VARCHAR(50),
  PRIMARY KEY  ( Username )
);

CREATE TABLE  AddressInformation  (
   AddressID  INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   Country  VARCHAR(50),
   ZipCode  VARCHAR(50),
   State  VARCHAR(50),
   City  VARCHAR(50),
   Street  VARCHAR(50),
   HouseNumber  VARCHAR(50),
  PRIMARY KEY  ( AddressID )
);

ALTER TABLE  PersonalInformation  ADD CONSTRAINT  PersonalInformation_fk1  FOREIGN KEY ( AddressID ) REFERENCES AddressInformation( AddressID );
```

And the code in my servlet:

```
private void toDatabase(PersonalBean p)
    {
        try
        {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/FoundationSystem","root","!Qaz2wsx");
            PreparedStatement stmt1;
            stmt1 = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO AddressInformation (Country, ZipCode, State, City, Street, HomeNumber) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)");
            stmt1.setString(2, "TestCountry");
            stmt1.setString(3, p.getFirstName());
            stmt1.setString(4, "TestState");
            stmt1.setString(5, "TestCity");
            stmt1.setString(6, "TestStreet");
            stmt1.setString(7, "TestHouse");
            stmt1.executeUpdate();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        { 
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
```

Comment: it is working...http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6e51a/1

Answer (score 2):

If my opinion all its all right. Look this

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/81082/1/0)

Comment: But when I use Eclipse to update it via sa Servlet, it doesn't increment

Answer (score 1):

The default size of an INT is 11, which is what would be here in  PersonalInformation:

```
AddressID  INT NOT NULL
```

but you've got 15 specified in your AddressInformation table:

```
AddressID  INT(15) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
```

Yes I would agree that this relationship is causing the dysfunction.

Resize the PersonalInformation to 15 and try again.